# angularJS filtring issue in Ionic app

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I am working on a simple products filtering app using Ionic framework.
I have a list of products that I like to filter, and the AngularJS filter model works great except for this weird case: If I scroll down the list and filter most of the search query is missing.

https://apps.ionic.io/app/11bc2ed5

```js
.factory('Recettes', function() {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
  var data = [];
  data.recettes = [];

  data.produits = [
    
    {
      "index": 1,
      "isActive": true,
      "estAutorise": 0,
      "name": "Howard Price",
      "marque": "in"
    },
    {
      "index": 2,
      "isActive": true,
      "estAutorise": 1,
      "name": "Ingrid Saunders",
      "marque": "amet"
    },

...
```

```html
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-header-bar class="item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Rechercher Un Produit" ng-model="searchText">
    </label>
    <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="searchText = undefined">
      Annuler
    </button>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content class="padding" >
    
    <div  class="list card" ng-repeat="produit in produits  | filter:searchText | orderBy: index">
      <div ng-switch on="{{produit.estAutorise}}">
        <div class="item item-autorise" ng-switch-when="1">
              <h2 class="title"><b>{{produit.marque}} </b>{{produit.name}}</h2>
              <b class="balanced">Autorisé</b>   
      ....
```

Here are few images that may describe the issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpwuQ.png

[Second Image], I'm typing the search while I am on top of the page, and every thing works fine.

[First Image][tird image] However, when I scroll down the list and insert the same query nothing shows.

I would really appreciate the help, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the filter is working, the problem in the view when I scroll down then filter that part of the screen become empty and the view stay there even if there is nothing to show there. I hope there is calToTop function that shift automatically to the top whenever the query is refreshed.